# strsplit by spaces greater than one in R

Tags: r, strsplit, stringr

Given a string,

```
mystr = "Average student score       88"
```

I wish to split if there are more than 1 space. I wish to obtain the following:

```
"Average student score" "88"
```

I searched that "\s+" will split by any number of spaces.

```
strsplit(mystr, "\\s+")
```

But this is not what I want. Is there any option within strsplit that can split strings based on a certain number of spaces (say space = k) or a rule on spaces (say space > 1)?

Comment: Another option is `scan(text=gsub("\\s{2,}", ",", mystr),what='', sep=',', quiet=TRUE)`

Comment: Spend time reading the `?regex` help page.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You may specify it through a repetition quantifier.

```
strsplit(mystr, "\\s{2,}")
```

`\\s{2,}` regex should match two or more spaces.

Comment: Thank you! Is there an option for matching an exact number of spaces too?

Comment: ya, remove the comma. `\\s{2}` for matching exactly two spaces,For 3, it would be `\\s{3}`, and to match min of 3 and max of 4 then it would be `\\s{3,4}`