# How do I split a string by more than one space into list elements in R?

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I need to split a string where there is more than one space into list elements. Let's say I have the following string:

```
"My name     is Bob and   I like programming."
```

I tried the following code:

```
library(stringr)
string <- "My name     is Bob and   I like programming."
strsplit(string,"\\s+")
```

Which gives the result:

```
[[1]]
[1] "My"           "name"         "is"          
[4] "Bob"          "and"          "I"           
[7] "like"         "programming."
```

However, I would like this result instead:

```
[[1]]
[1] My name

[[2]]
[1] is Bob and 

[[3]]
[1] I like programming.
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34916149/strsplit-by-spaces-greater-than-one-in-r

Comment: wow fail on my end, thanks!